# Almacenar un array multidimencional en una variable sin saber cuantas filas obtendra (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos

revisando uno de los algoritmos de freecodecamp en el que trabajamos con javascript tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

var largestNumber = [0,0,0,0];

for(var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arr.length; arrayIndex++) {

for(var subArrayIndex = 0; subArrayIndex < arr[arrayIndex].length; subArrayIndex++) {

if(arr[arrayIndex][subArrayIndex] > largestNumber[arrayIndex]) { 

      largestNumber[arrayIndex] = arr[arrayIndex][subArrayIndex];
    }
  }
}
return largestNumber;
}
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Como puedo declarar a "largestNumber" como un array multidimencionar sin saber cuantas filas obtendre?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad `largestNumber` no es un array multidimensional, es un array de una única dimensión cuya longitud depende de la longitud del array pasada a la función.

Puedes declarar el array sin necesidad de establecer su tamaño inicialmente.

Mira el ejemplo que te pongo con una pequeña modificación para tener en cuenta que el valor en el array `largestNumber` puede no estar inicializado.

También te pongo una función más simple que obtiene el mismo resultado utilizando los métodos `map` y `sort`.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {

  var largestNumber = [];

  for(var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arr.length; arrayIndex++) {

    for(var subArrayIndex = 0; subArrayIndex < arr[arrayIndex].length; subArrayIndex++) {

      if(arr[arrayIndex][subArrayIndex] > (largestNumber[arrayIndex] || 0)) { 
        largestNumber[arrayIndex] = arr[arrayIndex][subArrayIndex];
      }
    }
  }
  return largestNumber;
}

function largest2(arr){
  return arr.map(a => a.sort((x,y) => x<y)[0]);
}

var data = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
var result = largestOfFour(data);
console.log(result);
result= largest2(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu explicacacion!, ahora quisiera saber si el array que recibe la funcion largestOfFour es multidimencional o no?

Comment: Sí. Es un array de dos dimensiones.

Comment: Gracias, aprecio mucho tu respuesta amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Esto crea un array multidimensional sin especificar la longitud del mismo:

```
var largestNumber= new Array(0,0,0,0);
```